# Regex matching only second group

Tags: regex, rundeck

Is there any way that just match the string of second group by just using regex?

The tool I'm using is [Rundeck's Global Log Filters (Hightlight Output)](https://www.rundeck.com/blog/output-processing-data-passing-preview)

Tool description:

> Regular Expression to test. Use groups to selectively highlight. More
>   Use a non-grouped pattern to highlight entire match:
>
> regex: test message: this is a test result: this is a test Use regex
>   groups to only highlight grouped sections:
>
> regex: this (is) a (test) 
>   result: this *is* a *test* See the [Java Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
>   documentation.

Example:

```
3)  Manager port: 2614
4)  Tcp Port: 2615
3)  Manager port: 2714
4)  Tcp Port: 2715
```

Above is the strings, I want to get the match of `"3)  Manager port: 2714"` only. Here is what I come up `(?:Manager port:.*){1}`

But it still matching both `3)  Manager port: 2614` and `3)  Manager port: 2714`

Thanks

Comment: Sure, [`[\s\S]*\KManager port:.*`](https://regex101.com/r/p4SKqY/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: If you want only the second line that starts with "3)  Manager port: " you shouldn't use regex. a simple `String.startsWith()` would do the trick.

Comment: @JervisLin Are you sure it works in your target environment? Please check and let know. It is a PCRE/Onigmo/Boost/PyPi regex pattern only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for bringing that up. I just tested it and it didn't work on my environment. Mine is using Java pattern

Comment: @JervisLin Please post the code or name of the tool you are using the pattern in.

Comment: @alfasin I use rundeck's function log filter, which requires regex for the job

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've update my question to include the tool I'm using

Comment: So, you need `[\s\S]*(Manager port:.*)` or `(?s:.*)(Manager port:.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?:Manager port:.*){1}` is equal to `Manager port:.*` and just matches any `Manager:` substring and the rest of the line.

With a *java.util.regex* regex library, you may use

```
[\s\S]*(Manager port:.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p4SKqY/1)

**Details**

- `[\s\S]*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible (note that `[\s\S]` is a "hack", you may safely use `(?s:.*)` to do the same thing as `(?s:.*)` represents a modifier group with a DOTALL modifier turned on and thus `.` matches any char including line break chars)
- `(` - Capturing group start
- `Manager port:` - a literal substring
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.
- `)`  - capturing group end.

Comment: For some reasons, it still highlights both records in Rudeck. Not really sure the root cause of it

Comment: just put up the link to Question

Comment: @JervisLin No idea, really. It must be a bug, because the docs say this must work. Are you using the latest build? There was some update 10 days ago.

Comment: get a reply from Rundeck support mentioned **the Highlight Output Global Log Filter is applied “per line”, that is , it cannot filter multi line patterns**. I will take this as an answer since it works the way as described in the question.